# Xamarin app seems to be running same instance each time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm using xamarin in visual studio community for mac, a weird thing has come up the app seems to be running the same instance despite code changes, the reason I think this is I just changed appSetup to false and yet when I run the app and debug it is still equal to true even though explicitly set to false. It is extremely weird, I have already tried restarting visual studio and the android emulator.

Comment: Delete the app from emulator from manually and see

Comment: @ShiwankaChathuranga just did that it updated it to my current code when I ran it on a new device but then when I made another edit and ran it it again did not update to the new code.

Comment: @AppleGeek Try removing the "Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)" option in Android Project Properties/Android Options/Use Shared Runtime. That's not a long term solution - but might indicate the problem if it solves it.


I've never experienced this issue... what version of vs and forms are you on?

Comment: Your Visual Studio build settings could be set so the Android project is not being built. Check those settings and be sure to delete all `obj` and `bin` folders from each project, then rebuild.

Comment: In order to automate @hvaughan3 suggestion use https://github.com/yuv4ik/vsmacdeepclean . It is a free extension for VS for Mac.

Comment: @maplemale do you mean "Fast Assembly Deployment"? Because if so turning that off did nothing.

Comment: @AppleGeek This must have changed names in the newer versions. I do not have that exact setting in VS 2017 15.5.2. Or, perhaps Apple specific (I am on W10). See anything failing in the Build output window? I have had similar issues in older versions of VS (but not with Xamarin) where the plugin I was using would not detect changes in code (silverlight). That was a bug, and I noticed that toggling the "Define DEBUG constant" caused a refresh. Just something to try... maybe it is a bug. What version of Xamarin Forms are you running? (check nuget)

Comment: @maplemale there doesn't appear to be any errors and I cant find a "Define Debug Constant" setting.

Comment: @AppleGeek https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960602/when-if-debug-runs/12960644  look at picture in answer.

Comment: @maplemale it's not there

Comment: @AppleGeek You said "Visual Studio" in your question - but starting to think that's not the case. Do everyone a favor and click Help/About - tell us what it says.

Comment: @maplemale it's visual studio community for mac just like i said in the question

Comment: @AppleGeek Sorry - I didn't realize VS for Mac was so different! No more ideas here.

Comment: Is this any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210544/building-ios-app-does-not-update-on-iphone-or-simulator

Comment: Or this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45327/newest-version-of-code-not-always-deployed-when-debugging-from-xamarin-studio